# Extract only the contents of an archived directory from within an archive

Tags: command-line, tar, archive, extract

#### The Situation

I am extracting a CMS from *drupal-7.15.tar.gz* to */var/www*.

When extracted normally (with `tar -xvzf filename.tar.gz`) the files end up in */var/www/drupal-7.15/*

#### The Goal

I want the contents from the archived *drupal-7.15/* directory to extract directly into */var/www*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
 tar -xvzf filename.tar.gz --strip-components=1
```

`--strip-components=1` tells `tar` to strip the first path component (the `drupal-7.15/` in your case) from each file when unpacking.

Comment: Hallelujah. I just spent 10 minutes in Google Hell trying to get an answer to this simple question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and more user-friendly solution is to open nautilus using:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

Then head to your archive, double click it, wiat for it to open with the archive manager, double click into the directory (inside the archive manager, hit `Ctrl+A` so as to select all the files inside the directory, click on the "Extract" button, and then select /var/www/

Alternatively, you can just

```
sudo mv /var/www/drupal-7.15/* /var/www/
sudo rm -r /var/www/drupal-7.15
```